# Android app force closes when theme is set

Tags: java, android

I'm just getting started with Android dev, done a few tutorials, now I'm working on a simple app. On both the emulator and my phone (Android 4.0.3 emulator, Android 4.1.1 Atrix HD) apps are displaying in what I think is Holo Light. I'd rather have it be Holo Dark, but when I add the following line to the application block in the Android Manifest file: `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo"` the app compiles fine but force closes as soon as I open it.

What am I doing wrong? I'm sure it's something really simple, but as I said I'm new to this. Thanks in advance, y'all!

Comment: Add the LogCat (stack trace) that is produced when the app crashes. Also try cleaning your project, Eclipse may be messing up.

Comment: I can't help until you tell me what shows up in logcat. To get logcat, go to the window menu, Select show view, and select other. Click the arrow on the android folder, click log cat (Make sure it's not the one that has the word depreciated in it) then click ok. Run the app again and tell what message shows up when it crashes.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a theme for all the activities of your application then you need to use

```
<application android:theme="@style/CustomTheme">
```

in **AndroidManifest.xml**.If you want a theme applied to just one Activity in your application, then add the **android:theme** attribute to the **activity** tag instead.So need to know what type you use in your application.However see these things which will clear you more..
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html
http://www.androidengineer.com/2010/06/using-themes-in-android-applications.html

Comment: Hey, thanks so much for all the replies! However, I restarted my computer, Eclipse, the emulator, and cleaned the project as @A-C suggested, and now it work! Not sure what was going on before, but as long as it works now I'm happy. Thanks so much anyway though.

Comment: glad to see you got solution..:)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing you can do and you should always do is to read logs why does it crash. The log will tell you the reason of you crash. Please post the reason including logs from [Logcat](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html) and only then ask about fixes:)

Comment: I gave you all upvotes, and I'll use LogCat next time I have a problem.